# Clone repository from harbor using git

Tags: git, kubernetes, harbor

**Problem Statement:** Create 1 kubernetes kind deployment for an application . Application will run a web server which uses certain packages related files which will regularly get update in month time due as per customer requirement.

**Approach :** I am planning to create one init-container which will first create an empty pvc and will place package downloaded from repository and then that pvc can be mounted to main container from there docker-entrypoint.sh can execute required commands to run the application.

**Issue:** repository are hosted on Harbor with versions tagged.  how to pull those repository in our init-container?

Comment: as yoou mentioned in approach you will create init container and place package downloaded from repo, so not sure why you mentioned in issues how to pull those repo. can't you do `git pull` ?

Comment: The problem statement is not clear, also Harbor can't host repos only imgages